# Simplify select with count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I need to get some values from a database and count all rows.

I wrote this code:

```
SELECT author, alias, (select COUNT(*) from registry WHERE status='OK' AND type='H1') AS count
FROM registry
WHERE status='OK' AND type='H1'
```

It works, but, how can I simplify this code? Both `WERE` condition thereof.

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of this criteria by author? Look at using GROUP BY instead of a subselect

Comment: @ShadMickelberry: I guess he is trying to output total count in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query is returning the resultset you need, with the "total" count of rows (independent of author and alias), with the same exact value for "count" repeated on each row, we could rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT t.author
     , t.alias
     , s.count
  FROM registry t
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
           FROM registry c
          WHERE c.status='OK'
            AND c.type='H1'
       ) s
 WHERE t.status='OK'
   AND t.type='H1'
```

I don't know if that's any simpler, but to someone reading the statement, I think it makes it more clear what resultset is being returned.

(I also tend to favor avoiding any subquery in the SELECT list, unless there is a specific reason to add one.)

The resultset from this query is a bit odd. But absent any example data, expected output or any specification other than the original query, we're just guessing. The query in my answer replicates the results from the original query, in a way that's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT author, alias, count(1) AS caunt
FROM registry
WHERE status='OK' AND type='H1'
group by author, alias
```

Comment: We should provide a note that the result returned by this query is *significantly* different from the result returned by the original query.

Answer (score 0):

The **status** and **type** are the criteria to extract the fields from the table. You cannot go more simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a group by,

```
SELECT author, alias, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM registry
WHERE STATUS='OK' AND TYPE='H1'
GROUP BY author, alias
```

Depending on how your table is set up, you may actually need to do this to get the data you are looking for.

Some good reading for this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

However, if you are wanting the count to be simply ALL the records with that criteria, what you have may be simplest already.